# Is there an advantage in using when defining page objects in Protractor for AngularJS testing?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have seen two examples on how to create Page Objects:

The first example:

```
var LoginPage = function() {
   this.userName = element(by.input('login.userName'));
   this.password  = element(by.input('login.password'));
}
module.exports = new LoginPage();
```

and the second example:

```
AngularPage.prototype = Object.create({}, {
    todoText: { get: function () { return element(by.model('todoText')); }},
    addButton: { get: function () { return element(by.css('[value="add"]')); }},
  }}
});

module.exports = AngularPage;
```

Can someone explain the difference between these two. Is either one of these now recommended (used by the AngularJS team) over the other? Note that I am using the 1.0.0 version of Protractor for my testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the first style you get an instance of the object when you require the module. For example:

```
var angularPage = require('angular-page.js');
angularPage.create();
```

When you use second syntax you have to create a new instance yourself:

```
var AngularPage = require('angular-page.js');
var page = new AngularPage();
page.create();
```

I prefer the first syntax (`module.exports = new Page()`) because it is shorter. If you need to pass arguments to the constructor of your page object then you have to use the second syntax (`module.exports = Page`).

Comment: Hi..is there a documentation available for the PageObjects Syntax?

Comment: http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/page-objects and here is an example https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/website/test/e2e/api-page.js

Comment: Thanks for sharing these links..however, I am looking for a link which explains the syntax as you did in the Answer above. The way you explained, the syntax becomes clear. However, this is just a single case..there are many things like: field1: {get: function () { return smthng; }},
 field2: {value: function (idx) { return smthng_else; }},
So, is there a link which explains all the syntax